# Retrieve endpoint data from wp-json inside a add_action

Tags: wordpress

I have endpoint which has a page id of `2`. I would like to retrieve that value `2` which is the page id inside the WordPress RESTFul API Filter.

**Example:**

```
add_action( 'acf/rest_api/page/get_fields', function( $data ) {
    var_dump($data);
});
```

**My Endpoint:**
http://www.example.com/wp-json/acf/v3/pages/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_params](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/get_params/) to get the params. Below is the example how to implement it.

```
add_action( 'acf/rest_api/page/get_fields', function( $data, $request ) {
      $attributes = $request->get_params();
      $id = $attributes['id']; //Has #2 that's coming from the URL
});
```